# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I made function in my DAO implementation for running query

SQL QUERY :

```
  SELECT pct.IA_FILING_METHOD_CODE_ID, COUNT(*) 
            FROM Ia_Dossier pct 
            WHERE 1=1 and pct.INTERNATIONAL_FILING_DATE IS NOT NULL 
            AND pct.INTERNATIONAL_FILING_DATE>='11-SEP-08' 
            AND pct.INTERNATIONAL_FILING_DATE<='11-SEP-16' 
            GROUP BY pct.IA_FILING_METHOD_CODE_ID 
            HAVING pct.IA_FILING_METHOD_CODE_ID IS NOT NULL
```

This is running fine in db but giving error when run from hibernate code.

FUNCTION:

```
    @Override
    public List<Object[]> findStatsByROGroupedByFileFormat(Date startDate, Date endDate,String RO, String groupBy) {

        StringBuilder jpqlQuery = new StringBuilder();
        jpqlQuery.append("Select pct.").append(groupBy).append(",count(*) from IaDossier as pct where 1=1 and pct.internationalFilingDate is not null");
        if(startDate!=null)
        {
            jpqlQuery.append(" and pct.internationalFilingDate >=:startDate");
        }
        if(endDate!=null)
        {
            jpqlQuery.append(" and pct.internationalFilingDate <=:endDate");
        }

        if(groupBy!=null && RO!=""){
            jpqlQuery.append(" group by pct.").append(groupBy);
            jpqlQuery.append(" having pct.").append(groupBy).append(" is not null");
        }
System.out.println(jpqlQuery+"hc");
        Query q = entityManager.createQuery(jpqlQuery.toString());
        if(startDate!=null)
        {
            q.setParameter("startDate", startDate);
        }
        if(endDate!=null)
        {
            q.setParameter("endDate", endDate);
        }
        return (List<Object[]>)q.getResultList();
    }
```

CONSOLE:

```
12:09:45,572 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-2) Select pct.iaFilingMethod,count(*) from IaDossier as pct where 1=1 and pct.internationalFilingDate is not null and pct.internationalFilingDate >=:startDate and pct.internationalFilingDate <=:endDate group by pct.iaFilingMethod having pct.iaFilingMethod is not null

12:09:45,730 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-2) Hibernate: select iadossier0_.IA_FILING_METHOD_CODE_ID as col_0_0_, count(*) as col_1_0_, iafilingme1_.IA_FILING_METHOD_CODE_ID as IA1_52_, iafilingme1_.EN_NAME as EN2_52_, iafilingme1_.END_DATE as END3_52_, iafilingme1_.FR_NAME as FR4_52_, iafilingme1_.IS_EFILING as IS5_52_, iafilingme1_.OFFICE_RESTRICTIONS_APPLY as OFFICE6_52_, iafilingme1_.START_DATE as START7_52_ from IA_DOSSIER iadossier0_ inner join IBPROD.IA_FILING_METHODS iafilingme1_ on iadossier0_.IA_FILING_METHOD_CODE_ID=iafilingme1_.IA_FILING_METHOD_CODE_ID where 1=1 and (iadossier0_.INTERNATIONAL_FILING_DATE is not null) and iadossier0_.INTERNATIONAL_FILING_DATE>=? and iadossier0_.INTERNATIONAL_FILING_DATE<=? group by iadossier0_.IA_FILING_METHOD_CODE_ID having iadossier0_.IA_FILING_METHOD_CODE_ID is not null

12:09:46,076 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-2) SQL Error: 979, SQLState: 42000
12:09:46,078 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-2) ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

I don't know why it's giving this `GROUP BY` error when the query is running fine in sql developer.

Comment: I don't know anything about hibernate, but the first two lines from your console output look interesting. It appears you have two different SQL statements? The first one seems to be formed correctly, but the second one is definitely not. There are a number of elements in the second select that are not in the group by.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do??

When you use the `HAVING` clause you have to use an aggregation functions on the columns specified there, since you are grouping this query. I just changed it to a simple `WHERE` clause, no need to be specified in the `HAVING`.

```
SELECT pct.IA_FILING_METHOD_CODE_ID, COUNT(*) 
FROM Ia_Dossier pct 
WHERE pct.INTERNATIONAL_FILING_DATE IS NOT NULL 
    AND pct.INTERNATIONAL_FILING_DATE>='11-SEP-08' 
    AND pct.INTERNATIONAL_FILING_DATE<='11-SEP-16'
    AND pct.IA_FILING_METHOD_CODE_ID IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY pct.IA_FILING_METHOD_CODE_ID
```

> The Oracle HAVING clause is used in combination with the GROUP BY clause to restrict the groups of returned rows to only those whose the condition is TRUE.

Comment: i have change this as you said but again it's giving the same error

Comment: Select pct.IA_FILING_METHOD_CODE_ID,count(*) from Ia_Dossier pct
    where 1=1 and pct.INTERNATIONAL_FILING_DATE is not null 
    and pct.INTERNATIONAL_FILING_DATE>='11-SEP-08' 
  and pct.INTERNATIONAL_FILING_DATE<='11-SEP-16'  
    and pct.IA_FILING_METHOD_CODE_ID is not null 
    group by pct.IA_FILING_METHOD_CODE_ID

Answer (score 1):

What is the data displayed from the database if you run your sql code?
It could be that your `pct.IA_FILING_METHOD_CODE_ID` is `NULL`?

You must put all columns of the `SELECT` in the `GROUP BY` or use functions on them which compress the results to a single value (like `MIN`, `MAX` or `SUM`).

Try printing the entire `jpqlQuery` and compare it to the SQL you use in your DB.
(Also post both SQL Queries here)

More info about a [GROUP BY](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00979_not_a_group_by_expression.htm)

Comment: Select pct.iaFilingMethod,count(*) from IaDossier as pct where 1=1 and pct.internationalFilingDate is not null and pct.internationalFilingDate >=:startDate and pct.internationalFilingDate <=:endDate group by pct.iaFilingMethod having pct.iaFilingMethod is not null

Comment: in hebernate query it ibuilding joins for the filling code and taking out data from there

Answer (score 0):

i finally got to the reason of this error, in my jpa entity  IA_FILING_METHOD_CODE_ID was set to fetch.EAGER that's why it was making automatic joins to other table, thanks a lot for the help it moved me to the right direction. :)